# RegSetValueEx returns 998 (ERROR_NOACCESS) if called without ref

Tags: c#, pointers, winapi, visual-studio-2013, registry

I'm trying to write a DWORD to registry using c#.
Using p/invoke because of registry reddirection.

I've searched for this issue and finally could get it working but i don't understand.

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint RegSetValueEx(
             IntPtr hKey,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
     string lpValueName,
             int Reserved,
             RegistryValueKind dwType,
             ref IntPtr lpData,
             int cbData);

 int checkreturn = RegOpenKeyEx(HKeyLocalMachine, @"SOFTWARE\Test", 0, (int) RegistrySecurity.KEY_WOW64_64KEY | (int) RegistrySecurity.KEY_SET_VALUE, ref keyHandle);

            const int dataStored = 0;
            IntPtr p = new IntPtr(dataStored);
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(dataStored);
            uint checkreturn2 = RegSetValueEx(keyHandle, "valueName", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord, ref p, size);
```

This works if i put `out` or `ref` on lpData parameter, if i don't it returns error 998  (ERROR_NOACCESS), why is that? The same thing happens if i change the IntPtr to int, and pass the actual value, but this time i get an first exception AccessViolation on my code.

the winapi declaration for that it's `*lpData`, which i assume is what passing a `IntPtr` is.

```
  _In_       const BYTE    *lpData,
```

Comment: It is trying to tell you that you are not passing a valid pointer.  When you use VS2013 there is no remaining excuse to not use [RegistryView instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant There is if i don't want to use .net 4.0 or above...

Comment: Right, no excuse for using 7 year old free software either.  Time to move on, today is that time.

Comment: @HansPassant Don't wanna be picky, but it's not 7 years old afaik, and i'm using .net 3.5 which fits my needs atm, i know upgrading would make my life easier in this case (much easier) but this is an old project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api requires a pointer to the data plus the size of the data. You can't pass an `int`, or a `char`, or a `bool`. You need to pass a pointer to the data. If you pass something else, the API will interpret it as a pointer to the data, and random results will happen.

With P/Invoke, a `ref` to something is translated to a pointer to that something.

Now, you can

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint RegSetValueEx(
     IntPtr hKey,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
     string lpValueName,
     int Reserved,
     RegistryValueKind dwType,
     ref uint lpData,
     int cbData);
```

and then in `cbData` pass `sizeof(uint)` and *this* will work, because a `ref` for P/Invoke is a `ref`.

Only thing, I would suggest removing the

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
```

because without it the P/Invoke will use the Unicode version of the method, that is more correct.

Comment: so, i'm a little confused, if ref to something is a pointer, what does it do when i pass an IntPtr with no ref? It passes the value of the pointer itself instead of the underlying value to which it points? Is that it?

Comment: @SomeNickName For example, if you had a `byte[]` to pass, you could do `var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(yourByteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned); IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();` and pass it to a method with the signature `... RegistryValueKind dwType, IntPtr lpData, int cbData...`

Comment: ok thanks, in this case passing uint instead of IntPtr i understood why with ref it works and without it i get AccessViolation, it's because ref acts like a pointer... i'm more confused because i'm trying to learn c++ from a book atm and it's quite different, but now i get it.

Comment: @SomeNickName As a sidenote, `out` and `ref` "act" in the same way (they are translated to pointers to something), but you have to pass a value to the function, so you have to use `ref`. If you had received a value from the function then you could have used `out`